# Skipping unmatched input in Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is there a way to specify in a grammar that I want to skip all input that doesnt match any of the rules (that would otherwise throw a recognition error)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Implementation depends on where you need/want to do the skipping.

In the lexer, a last rule like:

```
Unknown : . -> skip ; // or -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

will consume any otherwise unmatched input characters yet keep them from being tokenized and considered by the parser. You do want to match a single character at a time so that at every input text index all other lexer rules have a chance to match first.

Similarly, in the parser, a last rule like:

```
ignored : . ;
```

will consume unmatched tokens, creating parse tree nodes, each as a context containing a single 'ignored' token.  Their presence in the parse-tree can then be, well, ignored.

Again, the ignored rule match should be for just a single token, ensuring that all other longer match rules have priority, and last in the ordering of the rules, ensuring that all other single token match rules are considered first.